# Javascript not working in all IE versions.. script with browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, IE won't execute this script (the 'else' part). I tried almost everything, but I can't manage it working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer") { 
        $(".f-top").corner("round 10px");   
        $(".s-top").corner("round 10px");
    }
    else {
        $('.f-top').css('background-image', 'url(../images/block-bg.png)');
    }
});
```

Comment: Which JS library are you using? i.e. JQuery, Prototype, etc.

Comment: @Barry: Of the two, that woudl be jQuery, not Prototype. Prototype's "select many" function is `$$`, not `$`. (And Prototype would be `setStyle` rather than `css`.) Of course, it may be neither.

Comment: *"I tried almost everything, but I can't manage it working."* Have you tried walking through the code step-by-step? IE8 and IE9 have a built-in debugger, and earlier versions can be debugged with the free edition of VS.Net. Here in 2011, there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using a proper debugger with your client-side JavaScript. :-)

Comment: You should **never** use browser detection for this. Simple `'borderRadius' in document.documentElement.style` can tell you if `border-radius` CSS property is supported.

Comment: please specify the versions of IE which work, and those which don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but it looks like you're trying to use JQuery to hack in rounded corners into your elements.

If you *must* use JQuery for this, there are plenty of good plugins already available which are better than your solution. Here's one: http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/61/

But frankly, the best way to do rounded corners in IE (all versions) is to forget about using JQuery, and use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) instead.

CSS3Pie is a small IE-specific hack which goes in your stylesheet, and makes IE work with the standard `border-radius` CSS property (which already works in all other browsers).

So all you need to have rounded corners is the following CSS:

```
#myElement {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Very easy, works well, and allows you to use standard CSS for all browsers.

See the examples and documentation on the CSS3Pie website for more details.

Comment: Great! Didn't knew this before, but this is by far the best solution for me until now.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are using jQuery - if so...

Use:

```
!$.browser.msie
```

Instead of:

```
navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, why don't you use the following?

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
  // do your thing if browser is Internet Explorer
}
else {
  // do your thing if browser is not Internet Explorer
}
```